# XML Data Driven Unit Test with nested Nodes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, data-driven-tests

I am not able to find something on the internet for the last hours. The situation is the following: I want to test a parser I have written, for this I have the desire to write a data driven unit test. The XML I have looks like the following:

```
<Test>
   <ParseTest>
      <Case>
         <uri>somestring</uri>
         <key>somestring</key>
         <value>somestring</value>
      </Case>
      <Case>
         <uri>somestring</uri>
         <key>somestring</key>
         <value>somestring</value>
      </Case>
   </ParseTest>
</Test>
```

Test is my root node for the whole class. The ParseTest should be the root for each method, so I want to access per run one case node with its childs

My testing code is:

```
[TestMethod]
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML",@"PATH\name.xml","ParseTest",DataAccessMethod.Seqential)]
public void ParseTest()
{
   //Arrange       
      m_testContext.DataRow["uri"].ToString();
   //Act
   //Assert
}
```

Problem with it is, that the Framework does not find the correct childnodes. The file is found correctly. I run the test via “Run test“ in VS.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more what the error is? Does the test framework not find the test, or the file? How are you running your tests (re# for example is shadow-copying test assemblies, which can lead to such errors)? Have you tried debugging (or output `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`)?

Comment: @PaulKertscher Better?

Comment: I am just looking up data driven tests with MSTest, gimme a sec.

Comment: How are you trying to access your test data?

Comment: I do not access the data. The MS Test Framework does this for me.

Comment: I know, that it *loads* the data from XML, but at some point you have to *"ask"* MSTest something like: "Please give me the current data."

Comment: Ah this. I am doing this with the test context class, but I am open for better options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this example](https://sylvester-lee.blogspot.de/2012/09/data-driven-unit-testing-with-xml.html) the additional `ParseTest` is redundant (or the nested `Case` tags are). As far as I have understood, the test framework will load all tags with the name `ParseTest` and run a test for each (given that you passed `"ParseTest"` as table name). Not knowing how you access the data from within your test I'd guess that the XML should like something like

```
<Test>
   <ParseTest>
      <uri>somestring</uri>
      <key>somestring</key>
      <value>somestring</value>
   </ParseTest>
   <ParseTest>
      <uri>somestring</uri>
      <key>somestring</key>
      <value>somestring</value>
   </ParseTest>
</Test>
```

Comment: Your solution works, but the problem is now that the unit test does not end. It iterates trough every element and then is waiting. I cannot describe in what state MSTest is because the debug runs perfectly okay but after pressing F11 after the last line it just waits...

Comment: Was missing a Environment.Exit(). With Dependency Injection it now works...